# Library for speech-recognition / speech-to-text

Tags: php, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to build an audio transcribing application for my organization which will at the end look like this from the front end

[image]

This will be a very simple speech to text feature.

I came across [**CMUSphinx**](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/) which look promising, but before spending time on this library, **I wanted to know if there are any other libraries that might suit my needs better?**

Do you have experience with any audio transcribing library which will do the job here?

---

P.S: I am tagging this question php, but am open to any suggestions here.

Comment: Transcribing is normally done by humans. Otherwise you won't need a webinterface at all. So can you please specify what your question is exactly about? Are you just looking for a speech recognition library?

Comment: Yes, a way to convert the audio to **text**, automatically, without using any humans :)

Comment: You are looking for speech to text, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583306/speech-to-text-api

Comment: Lazer, have you done speech-to-text job.I have to do same job for my organization.I searched a lot but not found convincing one

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SAPI (speech API) is perfect. I used it in the past and it works nicely